# parsing contents of string into substrings

Tags: c, linux, string

I am trying to read in a string from a file, then parse the contents of the string to determine how many children to create with fork(), and send each child a section of the string.

```
int main() {    
    FILE * fp = fopen("Makefiletest", "r");
    char * s;
    int i;
    char * e;
    int c;

    for (c = 0; c < 7; c++) {
        fgets(s, 128, fp);
    }
    //e = strchr(s, ":");
    //i = (int)(e - s);
    //printf("index of : is %d\n", i); 
    printf("%s", s);
    for (i = 0; s[i]; s[i]=='.' ? i++ : *s++);
    printf("%d\n", i);

    return 0;
}
```

which retrieves the line "`maketools.a: parse.o find.o`" 
`maketools.a` is a 2nd generation child (that will have received the string "`maketools.a`" from its parent), and needs to create 2 new 3rd generation children one with the string "`parse.o`" the other with "`find.o`".

I ran into a dead end when I was unable to get the index of `:` due to segmentation faults (it is commented out and replaced with an attempt I was trying to do with counting instead of strings (it failed)), which prevented me from dividing up the string.

UPDATE

```
    int main() {    
    FILE * fp = fopen("Makefiletest", "r");
    char * s[256];
    int i, index, ind;
    char * e;
    int c;

    for (c = 0; c < 7; c++) {
        fgets(s, 128, fp);
    }
    e = strchr(s, ":");
    index = (int)(e - s);
    printf("index of : is %d\n", index); 
    printf("%s", s);

    return 0;
}
```

UPDATE 2

```
int main () {   
    char fgets_string[256];
    char * fgets_string_ptr = fgets_string;
    strcpy(fgets_string_ptr, "      maketools.a:                      parse.o    find.o   ");
    char depen[6][128]; //[0][] is root, 1+ are dependencies
    char * depen_ptr;
    int c;

    while (isspace(* fgets_string_ptr)) {//removes leading whitepace
        fgets_string_ptr++;
    }
    for (c = 0; strlen(fgets_string_ptr) > 0; c++) {
        if (c == 0)
            strtok_r(fgets_string_ptr, ":", &depen_ptr);
        else {
            strtok_r(fgets_string_ptr, " ", &depen_ptr);
        }
        while (isspace(* depen_ptr)) {//removes leading whitespace
            depen_ptr++;
        }
        strcpy(depen[c], fgets_string_ptr);
        strcpy(fgets_string_ptr, depen_ptr);
        //printf("%s\n", depen[c]);
    }

    printf("%s\n", depen[0]);
    printf("%s\n", depen[1]);
    printf("%s\n", depen[2]);   

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `s` doesn't point to any valid place.

Comment: **Break the problem into smaller problems and solve one at a time.** You must 1) read a string from a file, 2) parse a string, and 3) create a variable number of children, sending each one a different string. Those three functions are independent, you can implement them in any order, but you ought not to combine them until all three work perfectly.

Comment: The part I am working on is breaking the string into substrings: the file and in this case both dependencies.  I've updated my post with my new code, with a pointer array declaration for s, and that cleared up the segmentation faults, but now I have a index issue "index of : is -409326864"

Comment: Unless you're targeting an ancient or obscure version of C, you don't need to forward-declare every local variable, it makes code quite unreadable, especially if you're using short, cryptic names.

Comment: "*The part I am working on is breaking the string into substrings*" no, you are not. You are still at reading from the file, because the calls to `fgets()` (as shown in both snippets) still invoke undefined behaviour by reading to where uninitialised pointers point. To define an array of 7 "strings" each 255 `char`s long use `char s[7][256];` Then pass to `fgets()` `s[c]`.

Comment: I was using the fgets for a static line that embodied all of the troubles I was having with reading the string.  I understand what you mean that I should break it down, at the time though, I thought it was the easiest way to work with it.  I hadn't seen the s[7][256] notation in my previous searches, thank you, I will read more about it and work with that.       Thank you for the insight, Dai, I will work on readability.

Comment: Thank you guys for all the help, updated version produces desired output (maketools.a \n parse.o \n find.o).  Now to change return type and incorporate it into rest of program.

Comment: You put `fork` in the title and as a tag, but this question has nothing at all to do with `fork()`, and it never appears in any of your code.

Comment: Because others told me to focus on one problem at a time I didn't pursue the fork any further in this topic, and I forgot to remove it from tag.  fork tag is gone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is a different approach to achieve what you want... Output of the code is

```
~/code/str % clang a.c -I../zstring -Wno-unused-value
~/code/str % ./a.out 
maketools.a
parse.o
find.o
~/code/str %
```

Instead of locating the `:` character first and dealing with spaces, you can split your string into tokens by using  (space) as the separator first, and then for the first string, you can remove `:` character.

The code below uses a string library I maintain, and can be downloaded from https://github.com/fnoyanisi/zString (available with BSD license)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <zstring.h>

int main(){
    char s[]="maketools.a: parse.o find.o";

    printf("%s\n",zStrrmv(zStrtok(s," "),":"));
    printf("%s\n",zStrtok(NULL," "));
    printf("%s\n",zStrtok(NULL," "));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I will do some experimenting with zStrtok and zStrrmv.  I am maintaining the `:` in the string as an identifier, I use it later to locate another sting I need to use.

Comment: In the context above, standard library's `strtok()` would do the same job for you as the one done by `zStrtok()`  (you may want to check the implementation of `zStrtok()` to see the differences).....

Comment: By the way, there is `zChrSearch()` function in zString that is similar to standardy library's `strchr()` but returns the index of the searched character rather than a pointer to it (there is not much difference to be honest, but may save you to do some pointer arithmetic). The problem with the string you are trying to parse is the presence of leading/trailing white spaces, which also act as the seperator for each pharase you are trying to get.